# What do the parentheses around `x === y` mean?

Tags: javascript

#### Example 1

```
var x = 123;              
var y = new Number(123);
(x === y)
```

#### Example 2

```
var x = 123;              
var y = new Number(123);
x === y
```

I looked at some code online and found those examples.

What's the difference between those two examples?

I don't understand why there are parentheses around the `x === y`?

Is `(x === y)` an expression?

Is `x === y` an expression?

Comment: In this particular case, there's no difference. And yes, both are expressions, of course.

Comment: Both are expressions, both have the same outcome in this context. They are evaluated and their computed value is dropped. If you run this code in the browser's webdeveloper console, the value is displayed in the console before being dropped.

Comment: `===` operator means `x` and `y` equals each other in the strictest sense down to type. In this case, parenthesis are optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking for any `x` where *x* is an expression, then `(x)` will also be an expression with the exact same result.

This is useful when grouping operations and declaring order of execution or just grouping items to be easier to read.

In some cases the parentheses are *not* part of the expression, but part of some other language construct, though, such as in this case:

```
if (x === y) {
  // stuff
}
```

Here only `x === y` is the expression and the parentheses are part of the if syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid expression and evaluates to either true or false, in this case both being false. Parentheses don't make a difference here, but it is very useful for grouping sub-expressions in large and complex expression.

Any statement that returns some sort of value is an expression. If you are still confused you can think of it as 'anything that can go on the right side of an assignment( = ) is a valid expression'.